# Where can I find best end of day option data?

Tags: options, historical-data, option-data

Looking for accurate end of day option data. Preferably with Greeks. Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you tried searching Quandl? https://www.quandl.com/search?query=&tags=%5B%22Options%22%5D&type=all

Answer (score 0):

Probably Option Metrics which you can find on WRDS is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A very decent place to get options data is https://www.historicaloptiondata.com. It is not free and I do not know anywhere you would be able to download such data for free. 
Re: options greeks there was discussion recently [historical options data](http://optionsforum.net/topic/232/where-to-download-historical-iv-for-free)